# Spring Integration DSL how to route split messages to different concurrent flows?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I probably hate writing noob questions as much as other people hate answering them, but here goes.

I need to split a message retrieved from a JdbcPollingChannelAdapter into multiple messages based on the operation requested in each row of the resultset in the payload.

The split operation is simple enough.  What is proving to be a challenge is conditionally routing the message to one flow or the other.

After much trial and error, I believe that this flow represents my intention

```
                                                    /- insertUpdateAdapter -\
Poll Table -> decorate headers -> split -> router -<                         >- aggregator -> cleanup
                                                    \---- deleteAdapter ----/
```

TO that end I have constructed this Java DSL:

```
    final JdbcOutboundGateway inboundAdapter = createInboundAdapter();;
    final JdbcOutboundGateway deleteAdapter = createDeleteAdapter();
    final JdbcOutboundGateway insertUpdateAdapter = createInsertUpdateAdapter();
    
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(setupAdapter,
                    c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).maxMessagesPerPoll(1)))
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression("start", "payload[0].get(\"start\")")
                    .headerExpression("end", "payload[0].get(\"end\")"))
            .handle(inboundAdapter)
            .split(insertDeleteSplitter)
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression("operation", "payload[0].get(\"operation\")"))
            .channel(c -> c.executor("stepTaskExecutor"))               
            .routeToRecipients (r -> r
                .recipientFlow("'I' == headers.operation or 'U' == headers.operation",
                            f -> f.handle(insertUpdateAdapter))

                // This element is complaining "Syntax error on token ")", ElidedSemicolonAndRightBrace expected"
                // Attempted to follow patterns from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference#routers
                .recipientFlow("'D' == headers.operation",
                            f -> f.handle(deleteAdapter))
                
                .defaultOutputToParentFlow())
                )
            .aggregate()
            .handle(cleanupAdapter)
            .get();
```

Assumptions I have made, based on prior work include:

1. The necessary channels are auto-created as Direct Channels
2. Route To Recipients is the appropriate tool for this function (I have also considered expression router, but the examples of how to add sub-flows were less clear than the Route To Recipients)
3. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert an `ExecutorChannel` somewhere between the splitter and router if you want to run the splits in parallel. You can limit the pool size of the executor to control the concurrency.

Comment: Do I understand correctly (see edited code sample)?

I still can't compile due to an "ElidedSemicolonAndRightBrace expected" error on the final recipientFlow element.

Comment: `.channel(MessageChannels.executor(stepTaskExecutor())`. You have an extra `)` on the next line.

Comment: Note that that documentation link is obsolete, the DSL was moved to the core project in 5.0. https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-routers

Comment: @GaryRussell how about putting ExecutorChannelSpec on @Router?

Comment: Don't ask supplemental questions in comments. Ask a new question with much more information.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra parenthesis after `.defaultOutputToParentFlow())`

The corrected code is:

```
        return IntegrationFlows
            .from(setupAdapter,
                    c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).maxMessagesPerPoll(1)))
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression("ALC_startTime", "payload[0].get(\"ALC_startTime\")")
                    .headerExpression("ALC_endTime", "payload[0].get(\"ALC_endTime\")"))
            .handle(inboundAdapter)
            .split(insertDeleteSplitter)
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression("ALC_operation", "payload[0].get(\"ALC_operation\")"))
            .channel(c -> c.executor(stepTaskExecutor))
            .routeToRecipients (r -> r
                .recipientFlow("'I' == headers.ALC_operation or 'U' == headers.ALC_operation",
                            f -> f.handle(insertUpdateAdapter))

                // This element is complaining "Syntax error on token ")", ElidedSemicolonAndRightBrace expected"
                // Attempted to follow patterns from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference#routers
                .recipientFlow("'D' == headers.ALC_operation",
                            f -> f.handle(deleteAdapter))
                .defaultOutputToParentFlow())
            .aggregate()
            .handle(cleanupAdapter)
            .get();
```